# How do I import face_recognition in Google Colaboratory?

Tags: python, installation, google-colaboratory, face-recognition

I'm working in Google Colab and have already imported dlib

```
!pip install dlib
import dlib
```

and installed face_recognition module.

```
!pip install face_recognition
```

But, I'm getting error for this line:

```
import face_recognition
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
import numpy as np
import cv2

%matplotlib inline
```

The error is as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-159-91aca6eea0d3> in <module>()
----> 1 import face_recognition
      2 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      3 from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
      4 from matplotlib.patches import Circle
      5 import numpy as np

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/face_recognition/api.py in <module>()
     24 
     25 cnn_face_detection_model = face_recognition_models.cnn_face_detector_model_location()
---> 26 cnn_face_detector = dlib.cnn_face_detection_model_v1(cnn_face_detection_model)
     27 
     28 face_recognition_model = face_recognition_models.face_recognition_model_location()

RuntimeError: Error while calling cudaGetDevice(&the_device_id) in file /tmp/pip-wheel-66glv9rf/dlib/dlib/cuda/gpu_data.cpp:201. code: 100, reason: no CUDA-capable device is detected
```

What can be done?

Comment: Sometimes looking at the error generated by compiler for a little bit of more time is better than searching for the same errors on internet. The error reason clearly states `reason: no CUDA-capable device is detected` CUDA capable GPU is needed in runtime. So, you need to select GPU and then install the library using `pip`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the error I can see you (probably) have not enabled GPU acceleration.

Go to Runtime -> Change Runtime -> **Select GPU**

Then Run the code `!pip install face_recognition`

This should install the library (and dependencies) without issue. Besides you don't need to install dlib separately. Let face_recognition build it alongside it. [image]